# How exactly do RGB curves work and interact w/each other in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, image-processing, curves

So I understand how a single curve works:

*If you create a curve such that R100 (in) becomes R50 (out), every pixel that has an R value of R100 becomes R50.*

Similar deal with the RGB curve:

*if you set RGB100 -> RGB50 any pixel that has R or G or B of 100 becomes 50.*

***So my question is***, I've set a RGB curve such that RGB100 -> RGB50 and R100 -> R125, the result is all R100 -> R73.  If I reverse that so RGB100 -> RGB125 and R100 -> R50, the result is all R100 -> R66.  If I set both RGB100 -> RGB50 and R100 -> R50, the result is all R100 -> R19...

What is the interaction there (mathematically) between the RGB curve and R curve?  This is all on the same curves layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hokay,
Turns out I was over-thinking the problem (no way!).  The answer is values from Curve1 go through Curve2.  So on the RGB100 -> RGB50 a R100 value becomes R50, then in the R100 -> R125 curve the R50 value becomes R73.

Voila.